# Problems with user's privileges, wordpress, phpmyadmin, my host provider and I hope that's all

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, privileges

So I've been trying to install a new wordpress site beside an already working site.
I want to have 2 different databases, so i created a new one, and I didn't go very far from that.
I get the message "Can’t select database" in /wp-admin/, and in the sql_error there is : 
"Access denied for user 'user'@'host' to database 'database'"

- After creating the database, and went to phpmyadmin to create a new user and his privileges, but there's no privileges tab in phpmyadmin. I did empty cookies and all, but with no effect.
- My host provider provides "mysql databases" tool. There is a drop list to make associations between schemas and users, so i did it, but there is no way to control that it's really taken into account
- I installed chive, but i can't find the privileges tab neither
- with sql queries, in phpmyadmin, i can't add any privileges, i get a "access denied to my_root_user on my_schema"
- It's the same errors when i try with an old user on the new schema.

Does somebody have a clue on what to try next ? 
If that comes from my provider configuration, how can i get the proof ?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Server configuration would be better on serverfault or superuser.

Comment: Maybe try [Wordpress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ richaux : they'll tell me it's not a wp probem for sure.

Comment: @ Marc B : ok thanks, I also posted there.